# CSS: prevent text overlap

Tags: css

I'm using some customized `<sub>...</sub>` to provide index subscripts in certain `<tt>` regions:

```
 tt.indexed sub
 {
     color:#0000ff;
     position:relative;
     top:0.5em;
     right:1em;
     margin-right:-0.5em;
 }
 tt.indexed sub:last-child
 {
     margin-right:-1em;
 }
```

Basically to pretty up stuff like 

0<sub>00</sub>0<sub>01</sub>
0<sub>02</sub>1<sub>03</sub>
1<sub>04</sub>0<sub>05</sub>
1<sub>06</sub>0<sub>07</sub>

and make it a bit more compact.

However, I'm having an issue where lines beneath my `<tt class="indexed">` regions overlaps the custom subscripts (just a little, but it's visually annoying).  I tried upping the `margin-bottom` on `tt.indexed sub`, but it didn't seem to have an effect.  Do I have to set a `margin-bottom` on `tt.indexed`, or is there a setting I can use in `tt.indexed sub`?

Comment: I always try using a padding when margin doesn't work. Try it once, it may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a line-height declaration with em.